# Get the next time occurance with linux date

Tags: linux, date

Linux `date` utility can understand a lot of strings including for instance:

```
$ date -d '8:30'
Fri Jan  2 08:30:00 CET 2015
```

I'm looking for a way to get the next `8:30`, thus:

- in case it is `Fri Jan 2` before `8:30`, the result above should be returned;
- otherwise it should print `Sat Jan 3 08:30:00 CET 2015`.

As one can see `next 8:30` doesn't result in the correct answer:

```
$ date -d 'next 8:30'
date: invalid date ‘next 8:30’
```

Is there a single expression to calculate this?

Handling it in the shell oneself is of course an option, but makes things more complicates because of *daylight save time* regulation etc.

In case the clock is adapted to daylight save time, `next 8:30` should be parsed to `8:30` according to the settings of the next day.

**Testcase**:

Given it is `Fri Jan  2 12:01:01 CET 2015`, the result should be:

```
$ date -d 'next 8:30'
Sat Jan  3 08:30:00 CET 2015

$ date -d 'next 15:30'
Fri Jan  2 15:30:00 CET 2015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched and it does not seem to be possible to do so.

What you can probably do is to compare the hour and minute with `830` and print accordingly:

```
[ $(date '+%H%M') -le 830 ] && date -d '8:30' || date -d '8:30 + 1 day'
```

In case you want to work with this easily, create a function to do these calculations.

#### Test

```
$ [ $(date '+%H%M') -le 830 ] && date '8:30' || date -d '8:30 + 1 day'
Sat Jan  3 08:30:00 CET 2015
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use something like:

```
if [[ $(date -d '8:30 today' +%s) -lt $(date +%s) ]] ; then
    next830="$(date -d '8:30 tomorrow')"
else
    next830="$(date -d '8:30 today')"
fi
```

The `%s` format string gives you seconds since the epoch so the `if` statement is basically:

```
if 8:30-today is before now:
    use 8:30-tomorrow
else
    use 8:30-today
```